# Does AOL mail allow oauth/3rd party application access

Tags: email, oauth, oauth-2.0, aol

I am wondering if AOL has had any recent changes that allow 3rd party developer access to accounts. Do they allow 3rd party applications that would access messages, via accesstokens and refreshtokens? This would be an application that downloads messages and analyzes their content. It would need to be able to access a user mailbox without the need for the AOL password.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes.
redirect the customer to:
https://api.login.aol.com/oauth2/request_auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&client_id=[client_id]

redirect_uri will have a code. Use it to grab access token from

Request details:
POST: https://api.login.aol.com/oauth2/get_token

params:
code:[oauth_code]
client_id:[client_id]
client_secret:[client_secret]
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:[redirect_uri]

response:
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "refresh_token": "wwww.www.www--",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}

I was able to fetch mail folders and mails using golang.
```